# Abrir novas páginas/links dentro da tab

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Achei interessante como o sistema abre as páginas "dentro de abas" e estou tentando fazer um similar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tendo dificuldades em abrir os links, mas não funciona, qual o meu erro?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //add ajax tabs
  $("#addNewAjaxTab").dynatabs({
    tabBodyID: "addajaxtabbody",
    showCloseBtn: true,
    confirmDelete: true
  });
});

function addNewTab(e) {
  $.addDynaTab({
    tabID: 'myTab',
    type: 'ajax',
    url: e + '.php',
    method: 'get',
    dtype: 'html',
    params: {},
    tabTitle: 'New Ajax Tab'
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Tabbed-Interface-With-Dynamic-Closeable-Tabs-Dynatabs/tabs.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Tabbed-Interface-With-Dynamic-Closeable-Tabs-Dynatabs/tdi.tabs.js"></script>

<p>
  <a href="#" id="addNewAjaxTab" onclick="javascript:addNewTab('pedido');">Link 1</a><br />
  <a href="#" id="addNewAjaxTab" onclick="javascript:addNewTab('pdvInterno');">Link 2</a><br/>

</p>


<div class="tabbable">
  <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#tabview1" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#tabview2" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div id="addajaxtabbody" class="tab-content tabcontents">
    <div class="tab-pane in active" id="tabview1">
      home tab content
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tabview2">
      profile tab content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pode ser com PHP e sem JS ?

Comment: @hugocsl amigo, toda ajuda é bem vinda. PHP seria boa.

Answer (score 1):

O primeiro problema é inserir páginas nos `hrefs` dos links:

```
<a href="link1.php"...
<a href="link2.php"...
<a href="link3.php"...
```

O uso de vários links para criar uma aba só faz sentido quando você deseja passar algum parâmetro individual de cada link, criando uma aba com um conteúdo específico passado via parâmetro ao Ajax.

Outra coisa sem sentido é usar uma página `.html` no Ajax usando múltiplos links, como visto acima. A página `.html` não será capaz de receber parâmetros e retornar código de acordo com esses parâmetros. **O código retornado no Ajax será o conteúdo da aba.**

**Vamos consertar isso:**

Primeira coisa é colocar `#` nos `hrefs`, para que não saia da página atual:

```
<p>
  <a href="#" name="addNewAjaxTab" id="addNewAjaxTab" onclick="javascript:addNewTab();">Link 1</a><br />
  <a href="#" name="addNewAjaxTab" id="addNewAjaxTab" onclick="javascript:addNewTab();">Link 2</a><br />
  <a href="#" name="addNewAjaxTab" id="addNewAjaxTab" onclick="javascript:addNewTab();">Link 3</a>
</p>
```

Caso você queira que cada link envie um conteúdo próprio para a nova aba, adicione um parâmetro em `onclick="javascript:addNewTab();"`, desta forma:

```
onclick="javascript:addNewTab('algum_parametro');"
```

Esse parâmetro será enviado via Ajax à uma página (veremos mais abaixo) que retornará um valor ou código de acordo com esse parâmetro.

Logo, essa parte do código ficaria:

```
<p>
  <a href="#" name="addNewAjaxTab" id="addNewAjaxTab" onclick="javascript:addNewTab('algum_parametro');">Link 1</a><br />
  <a href="#" name="addNewAjaxTab" id="addNewAjaxTab" onclick="javascript:addNewTab('outro_parametro');">Link 2</a><br />
  <a href="#" name="addNewAjaxTab" id="addNewAjaxTab" onclick="javascript:addNewTab('mais_um_parametro');">Link 3</a>
</p>
```

Veja que cada link está enviando um parâmetro próprio, que será recebido no Ajax desta forma:

```
function addNewTab(e) {

  $.addDynaTab({
    tabID: 'addajaxtab',
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'pagina.php',
    method: 'get',
    dtype: 'html',
    params: { parametro: e },
    tabTitle: 'New Ajax Tab'
  });
}
```

Adicionei um parâmetro `e` na função que será a variável enviada pelos links e passada no Ajax em `params: { parametro: e },`.

Veja que a *página alvo* do Ajax é um `.php`, que irá receber a variável `parametro` via `$_GET['parametro'];` e retornar o que você desejar se baseando no parâmetro enviado, e esse retorno será o conteúdo da nova aba.

> Notei que esse plugin não é compatível com versões mais recentes do
>   jQuery. Testei na versão 3 e não funcionou.

Caso você queira chamar o Ajax em páginas diferentes (e não uma só `pagina.php`), a lógica é a mesma: enviar no `javascript:addNewTab();` um parâmetro que pode ser a página que você quer usar, por exemplo:

```
<p>
  <a href="#" name="addNewAjaxTab" id="addNewAjaxTab" onclick="javascript:addNewTab('link1');">Link 1</a><br />
  <a href="#" name="addNewAjaxTab" id="addNewAjaxTab" onclick="javascript:addNewTab('link2');">Link 2</a><br />
  <a href="#" name="addNewAjaxTab" id="addNewAjaxTab" onclick="javascript:addNewTab('link3');">Link 3</a>
</p>
```

E no Ajax, mudar a *página alvo* dinamicamente:

```
function addNewTab(e) {

  $.addDynaTab({
    tabID: 'addajaxtab',
    type: 'ajax',
    url: e+'.php', // <-- aqui
    method: 'get',
    dtype: 'html',
    params: {},
    tabTitle: 'New Ajax Tab'
  });
}
```

Isso tudo é muito flexível e você pode usar como quiser conforme a sua necessidade. Se for explicar tudo aqui vai dar uma resposta enorme, mais do que já está. Por exemplo, pode usar `buttons` em vez de links `<a>` para adicionar as abas, fica até melhor na minha opinião.

Comment: dvd muito obrigado. **[1]** Por acaso você conhece algo similar, mas que seja com a versão do jQuery mais atual? Gostaria de iniciar esse projeto usando recursos mais novos, esse foi o mais proximo do que pretendo fazer. **[2]** Cada link ira abrir uma página, é possível passar o ``tabTitle`` via parametro, assim não precisaria criar uma função para cada link. Obrigado

Comment: Obrigado. Vou aguardar a resposta do @hugocsl, parece que ele tem um em php.

Comment: vou atualizar meu código inicial, poderia ver se consegue ajudar onde estou errado? Estou pegando um código da web e tentando adaptar ao meu framework. Atualizo em 2 minutos.

Comment: não esta sendo carregado a página dentro da tab e nem criada a tab com o titulo.

Comment: Joia, obrigado.

Comment: @Tiago Dá uma olhada http://dvdteste.hospedagemdesites.ws/abas.php